# Custom components that can extend beyond their container's bounds - how?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Let's say you have a JPanel size 200 x 200, with a custom combo-box-type component whose dropdown list should be able to extend outside of the 200 x 200 JPanel.

The problem I'm facing is that the dropdown either doesn't 'paint' outside the bounds of the container, or the container is sized according to the dropdown.

How can I add a component to a container which allows that component to extends beyond the bounds of the container? How does the Java JComboBox do that internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a [JPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html) for the dropdown. JPopupMenu internally will handle painting at and beyond the edges.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Answer (score 1):

if you continue with development of aplication that screenshots you posted here, you have to look for how to use [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) (undecorated Top-Level Container), as example some of the best of [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/), [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/projects.jsp), for full_workaround about `setVisible` / `toFront` / `FocusSubsystem` / on `focusGained/focusLost`

there no issue set `JWindow` to the `Point` with `setSize` that you can returns from any of JComponent

Comment: What benefit would using JWindow have over using an undecorated JFrame?

Comment: its Too hard to manage focus / toFront / toBack betweens two JFrames, for that is there JDialog/JWindow, carefully with JPopup and JCombobox, http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4799266